# Appointment item bug on copying text

Tags: vba, outlook, formatting, appointment

Im working on this code to create an Outlook appointment from Excel. And a part of this code is to insert a formatted text inside the Body, once the AppointmentItem isn't formattable at all.
It works like that:

- I first create an MailItem, and use the HTMLBody to insert and format my text.
- Not even need to Display this item, and I use a command to copy the formatted text (storing the text in the Windows clipboard [CTRL+C]).
- Now I create the AppointmentItem and use another command to paste the text inside the Appointment Body (Not exactly the text, but everything which is inside Windows clipboard [CTRL+V]).

Well, works fine, but I would like to avoid this CTRL+C_&_CTRL+V thing, if it is even possible. But this isn't my main concern since I'm getting these "bugs":

- First bug: If I load this code twice in a row, It should display two Outlook appointments, each one with the formatted text. But the first appointment shows the text duplicated, and the second one shows nothing. Img:
  [image: First bug]
- Second bug: Im using a code to unlock the Word document (since Im using *.GetInspector.WordEditor* Property), but even using this code, sometimes he shows this error and highlight the `B5.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)` line:

> *This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing.*

But sometimes works fine.

Well, that is it, sorry about this topic so huge. But I have no idea what is happening.

My code:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'========================================================================================
'//EMAIL
'========================================================================================
Set ItemEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

With ItemEmail
    .HTMLBody = " <b>text text text</b> "
End With

Set A1 = ItemEmail
Set A2 = A1.GetInspector
Set A3 = A2.WordEditor
Set A4 = A3.Range

'//Protected file
Set Protegido = ItemEmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
If Protegido.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    Protegido.Unprotect
End If

A4.FormattedText.Copy

ItemEmail.Close (olDiscard)
'________________________________________________________


'========================================================================================
'// APPOINTMENT
'========================================================================================
Set ItemAppoint = oApp.CreateItem(1)

With ItemAppoint
    .Display
End With

'//Protected file
Set Protegido = ItemEmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
If Protegido.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    Protegido.Unprotect
End If

Set B1 = ItemAppoint
Set B2 = B1.GetInspector
Set B3 = B2.WordEditor
Set B4 = B3.Application
Set B5 = B4.Selection

B5.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
'______________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an appointment in Outlook, using Excel, run the script below.

```
Private Sub Add_Appointments_To_Outlook_Calendar()

    'Include Microsoft Outlook nn.nn Object Library from Tools -> References
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Remind_Time As Double

    i = 2
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

    'Loop through entire list of Reminders to be added
    While Subj <> ""
        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Subj
        oAppt.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) * 60 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6)
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save

        i = i + 1
        Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Wend
    MsgBox "Reminder(s) Added To Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

‘ The code comes from this link:
‘ http://officetricks.com/add-appointment-to-outlook-calendar-through-excel-macro-vba/